# Trotterizing a Pauli sum in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

In Qiskit, how do I construct a circuit corresponding to the Trotter expansion of a Pauli sum $A+B+C+\ldots$ given as a `WightedPauliSum` object?

$$
\operatorname{e}^{A + B + C + \ldots } \overset{?}{\mapsto}
\left\{\begin{alignedat}{9}
U &= \operatorname{e}^{A}\operatorname{e}^{B}\operatorname{e}^{C}\ldots \ &&, \quad &&\text{(first order)}\\
U &= \operatorname{e}^{A/2}\operatorname{e}^{B/2}\operatorname{e}^{C/2}\ldots\operatorname{e}^{C/2}\operatorname{e}^{B/2}\operatorname{e}^{A/2} \ &&, \quad &&\text{(second order)}\\
 & \ldots
\end{alignedat}\right.
$$
I guess, `PauliTrotterEvolution` should do the job, but I have not found a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```
qc_trotter = paulistring.evolve( evo_time = 1, 
                                 expansion_order = 2)
```

where `qc_trotter` is an object of type `WeightedPauliOperator`, see [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.operators.legacy.WeightedPauliOperator.evolve.html).

Be mindful though that using circuits generated in this way may sometimes result in errors, as reported [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues/1034).

Comment: Please add some details, for example link to used function documentation etc.